# When is it reasonable to use getInstance/new class()? (PHP)

Tags: php, class, instance

I've got a basic question:

When I'm developing PHP I often wonder, when is it reasonable to use    `exampleclass::getInstance()`
and when to use `new exampleclass()`

When should I use which one? and what is the big difference between them?
I just want to get out the "best practice" out of that issue.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class that implements a `getInstance()` method is usually a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). In this case, you should basically never use `new exampleclass()`. (Actually, calling the constructor directly should be forbidden after all.)

A singleton assumes that one instance of its class at most exists during the program's lifetime. If there were more instances, they could conflict with each other which would cause some ugly problems. (For example, the singleton could access some globally available functions or methods or open some connection to another module or another network location. If two instances write to the same variables without knowning about each other, the system could get into a state where it does not know how to continue working.)

Comment: Great, thank you. But why is it bad to call the constructor directly?

Comment: @hayo Because the singleton is intended to create only one instance. Calling the constructor almways create a new instance. In a singleton, the constructor is usually private, avoiding people from calling it accidentally.

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, `getInstance()` is used in the case of a [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), that is when you need to always use the same instance of object. In this case, the `getInstance` calls a usually private constructor only on the first call.

A `new ExampleClass()` will create a new instance of this class on each call.